# Multi-Valued Managed Properties with FAST Search Server and SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, fast-esp

My scenario is a  SharePoint 2010 environment with installed FAST Search Server. I am using the SharePoint KeywordQuery class with FQL (Fast Query Language) to execute queries against the FAST index.

My problem:
Apparently Fast Search Server 'does not support data type awareness in the returned query results' (as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407618.aspx)). This means that for managed properties that are mapped to multiple crawled properties (e.g. "Author") the engine will only return a single string containing all values. (SharePoint search would return an array of strings in that case.)

I need to be able to distinguish between the different values, therefore I have tried to find possible solutions for that problem. Here is what I found so far:

1. Implement a [Custom Property Extractor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795797.aspx) and introduce a separator for different values.
2. Modify e.g. FAST configuration files (e.g. C:\FASTSearch\index-profiles\deployment-ready-index-profile.xml) and introduce a separator for different values.
3. Use the refiner functionality of the KeywordQuery class (ResultType.RefinementResults) and try a mapping between the refiner results and the search results.

Both 1 and 2 are not recommendable in my opinion as they would change the behavior of 'standard' managed properties which would have impact on the overall system (e.g. on a FAST Search Center site). Moreover, 2 seems to be forbidden by MS as the config files would be replaced by any FAST update. 3 seems to be a highly expensive operation.

Are there any other solutions I have missed? Any advice is highly appreciated...

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you had any luck with this? We are facing the exact same issue in trying to get multi valued metadata returning in our search result set.

Comment: @xazos79: Did you get any solution to your problem?